# Table header shifted in printout

Tags: printing, sapui5

We are using sap.ui.table.Table on different pages of the app and we run into the issue that the table header is shifted from the rest of the table in printouts. I've attached two screens, one showing the table as rendered in browser, the other one the misaligned printout.

[image: Table in browser]
[image: Shifted printout]

It looks like the width of the header cells get adapted by javascript (visible when resizing the document) which does not work when printing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a screenshot and then print the screenshot instead of the web page itself.